# how to Bind dropdownList using Entity Framework in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, html.dropdownlistfor

i want to show a `dropdownList` on a page using `Entity Framework` in my `MVC` app, but i am just stuck here to do this using using HTML Helper. so if anyone having knowledge of entity framework, help me...

my dataContext partial class is `Entities`, in which an entity named `MemberInfo` have some fields including `MemberID` & `MemberName`, so my dropdownList should show the field `MemberName` & behind this the value should be `MemberID`,

the code i tried yet--->

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.MemberID, MemberInfo)
```

in controller i am returning the Model--->

```
var MemberNameList = FinanceDBContext.MemberInfoes.Select(x => new { x.MemberID, x.Name });
return View(MemberNameList);
```

but its not working (`errors`).

Comment: What are the errors? Is your view strongly-typed? There are lots of examples on SO of how to achieve this, have you searched?

Comment: the `MemberNameList` i am returning to the view, how to use this to show the dropdownList. the first line of code above is not valid (second arg shd b an enumerable type).

Comment: can u rewrite this line with right syntex, i'v googled alot, but not found any suitable answer !

Comment: I've put full example of showing list and getting who was selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in all of your objects as the "model". Best practice is to use a **ViewModel** which will contain the list of data and a property to store the selected item.

**ViewModel**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    // The drop-down list and variable to get selection
    public List<Member> Members { get; set; }
    public int SelectedMemberId { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel();
    viewModel.Members = FinanceDBContext.MemberInfoes.ToList();
    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
    string debug = string.Format("You selected member: {0}", viewModel.SelectedMemberId);
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

**Finally, in your view** (these lines need to be inside a BeginForm { ... } and ensure your View is strongly typed to `MyViewModel`

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedMemberId", new SelectList(Model.Members, "MemberID", "Name"))
<input type="submit" value="Save etc..." />
```

In this example you could put a break-point on the `HttpPost` action and check the debug string to check the correct Member is returned and proceed as required.

Comment: `The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor<TModel,TProperty>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Comment: That is because your view should be strongly typed to "MyViewModel" not "SelectListItem" - I've added that note in instructions.

Comment: nope !!! this is bcoz u'v wrote `DropDownListFor` instead of `DropDownList`. Now its working, thanx for ur answer.

Comment: yeah sure, can u help me in one more thing. i want to show selected `member name` in a label Text (whenever user selects a option, that label text shd change as selected value (`MemberID`) )

Comment: If you want to do it when they change the selection you will need to do this with JavaScript (or JQuery etc).